# Getting auto-completion to work in an IDE using Coffeescript and external Javascript libraries such as jQuery

Tags: ide, autocomplete, coffeescript

I would like to ask how other more experienced Coffeescript developers are using their respective IDE's or editors with auto-complete when developing modular libraries and / or referencing external Javascript libraries (jQuery, jQuery UI, RequireJS, Handlebars, ...).

As much as I've tried various IDE's and plug-ins for Coffeescript, none of these seem to support auto-completion when the project consists of several script files. For example: in Visual Studio I can add a commented directive such as `/// <reference path="/js/jquery.js" />`. I'd need something similar for Coffeescript.

I have tried following without success:

1. Visual Studio with Web Workbench by Mindscape
2. Netbeans with dstepanov's Coffeescript plug-in
3. Aptana with the Coffeescript ruble

Further, I am aware of Jetbrain's WebStorm 3.x support for Coffeescript, unfortunately, my evaluation period expired before I realized I'd need this feature - can anyone confirm that setting the Javascript / Coffeescript Usage Scope works as expected with auto-complete?

So effectively what I am asking: is there an IDE or plug-in, commercial or otherwise,  enabling auto-complete for Coffeescript libraries spanning multiple files?

Comment: I was hoping too. But seems [nothing yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665747/jquery-intellisence-in-vs2010-when-writing-coffeesript#comment10771473_8665747)

Comment: Ah..my search missed your question here, sorry 'bout that. It's true though, as for now, I see little value in Web Workbench for Coffeescript as it does little more than add syntax coloring. It wouldn't even do auto-complete for coffee classes written in other files yet contained within the same project - big fail as far as I am concerned, but I'll be watching their efforts and hope they can improve their add-in in future releases!

Comment: Yes indeed. They [have intention to add this feature](http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/249116). But I guess not so soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but after giving JetBrains WebStorm 3.0.2 another demo run on another box, I figured it worked best and does have 'smarter than average' auto-complete for coffeescript projects. It simply loads all coffeescript files in to a global auto-complete context and you can add external libs (cs or js) as well using the project's scope settings. Could be better, but for now I cannot find any other IDE or tool running on PC or Linux, OSS or paid, that tops WebStorm and I don't have the fortunes to explore OSX alleys.

I am sure future tools, plugins, IDE's will pop up for various platforms that do offer great coffeescript module management and proper contextual auto-completion in the editor. So please, do keep the suggestions coming.

Thanks!

Comment: Tooling support like this is one reason I prefer TypeScript over CoffeeScript. It helps a lot when your IDE knows everything about your code tree.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use Kdevelop. I can't remember if I installed a plugins or something to get it work with coffeescript.
But it works very well, the highlighting colors are pretty, when ctrl+d it add coffeescript commentary and so on.
Also I do make compilation directly in KDevleop.

Well also it's free, I am using it on linux debian but I think it works on most platforms.

Check it there : http://kdevelop.org/

Comment: Tried getting the latest KDevelop binary for Windows, but that just hung up on me upon installing. I'll give it a spin at home on Ubuntu and see how it fairs up against my spoiled coder intellisense requirements ;)

Comment: Well, not too shabby overall, but yet again, not much more than fancy syntax colouring. I was looking for something that could recognize and offer auto-complete after doing `require("lib.coffee")` module imports or auto-complete on a cs / js lib in global context and so on and so forth. Also only got it working on Ubuntu - just wouldn't run on 2 different Win7 x64 boxes so that rules it out for office use.